# Creating a post using PHP in one of the blogs in WP MU

Tags: wordpress

I have a PHP program to create a site/blog in a networking enabled WordPress. After the site creation, I want to create a post using the same PHP program.

If I use `wp_insert_post()` function, it's creating the post in the main site/blog, not in the new site/blog I created. I also tried using `switch_to_blog()` before calling the `wp_insert_post()` but no luck.

Comment: switch_to_blog should solve your problem. Could you describe how are you doing it?

Comment: $blog_id=wpmu_create_blog('10.10.10.10', '/cc1/','cc1', 'admin', '', 1);
switch_to_blog($blog_id);

$my_post = array (
        'post_title' => "POST:".$title,
        'post_content' => $content,
        'post_status' => 'publish'
);

$post_id = wp_insert_post( $my_post);

Comment: I got the answer for this... The culprit is $blog_id, the moment I changed the variable name to $new_blog_id, it started working. Thanks.

Comment: Send it answer and mark it as correct :) So it could help others!

Comment: @M99 Thanks, that was the problem. Such a simple thing :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer for this... The culprit is $blog_id, the moment I changed the variable name to $new_blog_id, it started working. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The following used as [Must Use](http://codex.wordpress.org/Must_Use_Plugins) plugin does the job:

```
<?php
/* Plugin Name: New Post on Site Creation */

add_action( 'wpmu_new_blog', 'default_post_so_5334372', 10, 6 );

function default_post_so_5334372( $blog_id, $user_id, $domain, $path, $site_id, $meta )
{
    switch_to_blog( $blog_id );
    $my_post = array(
      'post_title'    => 'My post',
      'post_content'  => 'This is my post.',
      'post_status'   => 'publish',
      'post_author'   => 1
    );
    wp_insert_post( $my_post );
    restore_current_blog();
}
```